# ¿Cual es la librería de gráficos mas eficiente en javascript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Cual es la librería que tiene un mejor rendimiento en javascript, en cuanto a visualización de muchos datos? También cual es la que menos recursos de procesamiento necesita?

Comment: Hay una comunidad para recomendaciones de software, posiblemente te puedan ayudar allí mejor: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer: me largué a escribir sin procesar el espíritu de la pregunta :plaf** Ví que decía ReactJS y saqué conclusiones apresuradas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

De todos modos dejaré la respuesta de recuerdo:

Creo que la pregunta parece basada en opiniones pero, habiendo usado las tres, hay datos duros que respaldan algunos pros y contras. Mejor rendimiento en javascript puede significar menos features, o menos escalabilidad. Hay librerías que vuelan manejando un componente pero cuando son 200 componentes el bus se convierte en un cuello de botella.

Analizando los tres frameworks más populares:

[**React**](https://reactjs.org/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

React es en el fondo una librería de frontend, no es en sí un framework ni implementa un patrón MVC (más bien la lógica va en la vista, whatever) pero le puedes añadir todos los componentes del ecosistema que quieras para hacerlo más frameworkistico.

- ✓ Vuela en performance
- ✓ SSR (renderizar componentes en el servidor y no al vuelo) nativo
- ✓ Escala decentemente en aplicaciones más grandes, pero hay cierto impacto
- ✓ Es la librería más usada en este momento y la comunidad es sólida y respaldada por Facebook. Hoy en día si sabes react no te van a faltar ofertas de trabajo en los próximos 3 años cuando menos
- ✘ La curva de aprendizaje puede ser un poco empinada
- ✘ La sintaxis es una mezcla de javascript con html (JSX) que no es intuitiva de leer para un nuevo desarrollador que se une a un proyecto. Aunque seas el dios de JSX, no te puedes imaginar el layout viendo el código. Aprender JSX no te hará mejor desarrollador. Sólo te acostumbrará a que vivimos en tiempos extraño.

  - ✘ de la mano con lo anterior, React se ha negado a implementar un sistema de templating y tener todo en javascript rompe el principio de separación de responsabilidad, aunque eso no está escrito en fuego

[**Angular**](https://angularjs.org/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Angular es un framework y eso implica que para hacer un hola mundo hay harto boilerplate que meterle, pero cubre todas las aristas. Trae todo lo que puedes necesitar y lo que no puedas necesitar también.

- ✘ El performance en cuanto a rendering es muy bueno, pero el uso de memoria se dispara en apps complejas (hablo de SPAs donde todo existe desde la primera carga pero se rehidrata bajo ciertas condiciones y rutas). Angular usa el patrón observable y le mete observables a todo.
- ✓ A cambio de lo anterior, todo tiene two way data binding, no hay que añadir nada para incorporar ese comportamiento
- ✘ Soporta SSR pero requiere el componente Angular Universal
- ✘ Harto breaking change entre versiones
- ✓ Tiene el respaldo de Google y está pensada desde los cimientos para usar material design, que como lenguaje visual es buena idea porque viendo una app con material design ya sabes donde está todo y qué significa un botón redondo abajo a la derecha, por ejemplo.
- ✘ Hoy en día anda a la baja respecto a React
- ✘ La curva de aprendizaje es más empinada que la de React
- ✓ Utiliza TypeScript (en rigor puedes trabajar sin TS) que es un superset de javascript con typecasting, y eso a la larga te hace programar mejor y hace tu código ideal para análisis estático reduciendo la incidencia de bugs por coerción implícita.
- ✓ La sintaxis te empuja a usar inyección de dependencias y eso también es una excelente práctica y facilita la reusabilidad de componentes.
- ✓ Aunque Angular vaya a la baja, TypeScript va al alza. Los que pasaron 4 años trabajando con Angular ya debieran pensar en cambiarse, pero no es tiempo perdido. El Typescript aprendido les va a servir mucho y se está usando en todo.

[**VueJS**](http://vuejs.org/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vue está pensado para ser implementado progresivamente. Si quieres usarlo sólo para hacer un componente y meterlo en una webapp existente, no hay problema. De ahí puedes pasar a manejar los modelos, de ahí puedes añadirle los módulos más sólidos para manejar el estado (vuex) las peticiones asíncronas (axios) y más. No es en rigor un framework porque no trae cosas que no necesitas en apps simples como un sitio web estático.

El autor es Evan You (chino) y el uso de Vue es preponderante en China, Korea, Japón, etc. El núcleo más leal de early adopters es chino y los complementos y generadores más reconocidos de Vue en su momento (digamos, el 2016 o 2017) tenían bastante chino en su código. Eso les significó que para internacionalizarse se ocuparon de traducir toda la documentación, en muchos casos no sólo al inglés.

- ✓ Escala perfecto y es incluso un poco más rápido que React en este aspecto en aplicaciones pequeñas. En aplicaciones SPA grandes es notoria su ventaja (aunque todas las webapps son distintas, y algunas son más distintas que otras, diría Orwell)
- ✓ Utiliza JS/HTML/CSS común y corriente, ves el código de un componente y en 30 segundos se entiende lo que hace.
- ✓ La curva de aprendizaje es mínima
- ✘ No tiene el respaldo de un gigante del software, por lo que en muchos aspectos su desarrollo es orgánico y no sigue un paradigma uniforme.
- ✓ Considerando que Goole usa Angular para sus apps, y facebook React para sus app, si un día deciden cambiar todo será una decisión de negocios (ya pasó con flash, silverlight, y muchos otros). Vue no corre riesgo de ser desechado porque existe como proyecto para sí mismo.
- ✘ No es tan conocido como React ni Angular. Hay poca demanda específica para desarrolladores Vue en el mercado
- ✓ Si bien no es tan conocido la comunidad es bullante y muy agradable
- ✘ No tiene el apoyo de un gigante (pura donación)
- ✘ No tiene lineamientos de diseño consistentes, así que puedes hacer un mamarracho
- ✓ Lo anterior permitió que se crearan librerías de UI que llenan ese espacio y lo hacen muy bien. Vuetify, Bootstrap-Vue, Element-UI, Quasar se integran muy consistentemente con la librería dado que ésta deja esa elección al consumidor
- ✓ Esas librerías, de entre las cuales muchas son de los early adopters chinos, vienen con soporte para múltiples idiomas. En vez de asumir que todos saben inglés (como hacen los otros dos) acá el aspecto i18n es ciudadano de primer nivel.

---

Si estás pensando en aprender uno de estos frameworks/librerías, tienes que considerar si lo quieres para hacer un app en particular y qué tamaño tendrá tu aplicación. O bien si es para buscar trabajo, mejor ir por lo más demandado. O si quieres aprender y prototipear rápido, qué es lo más eficiente.

Yo sé usar las tres, y me gusta VueJS. Sin embargo la oferta de empleos para React es tan amplia que si no tuviera trabajo me pondría a aprender ahora mismo (bueno, ya sé React, pero no para pasar una entrevista de trabajo).

Si tienes un solo componente y una lista gigante que no necesita reaccionar a llamadas asíncronas, cambios de estado, etc, Angular probablemente le gane a los otros dos en velocidad, pero lo notarás poco. Si hay que manejar inserción y permutación de filas, probablemente gane React, pero cuando trates de hacer algo que no está en el tutorial la cosa no pinta bien. Si tu aplicación con el tiempo tendrá N componentes, posiblemente en un año habrás querido usar Vue. A menos que se queden sin plata y desaparezca :D

Comment: Aunque como respuesta esta muy buena, pregunta por librerias de graficos. Estas tres son frameworks, pero ninguna incluye una libreria de graficos.

Comment: "El autor es Evan Yu (chino) y la documentación suele estar en chino pero con buenas traducciones gracias a que es un framework popular en europa.", Podrías explicarme ¿de dónde has sacado eso, por favor?

Comment: Muy buena explicación, lastimosamente no es la respuesta para la pregunta. Pero igual muchas gracias.

Comment: @fredyfx en realidad, releyendo lo que puse, debo haber estado desvariando jejeje. Encima respondí a algo que no me preguntaron. Debiera borrar esta cosa pero me tomé al menos una hora

Comment: @JUANFERNANDONARVAEZGALLEGO oye pero... tu pregunta tiene el tag reactjs, de ahí partió mi papelón

Comment: @amenadiel muy buena la respuesta... es una pena que no se encuentre luego hare la pregunta para esta respuesta

Comment: la respuesta es interesante, pero no corresponde a la pregunta, tal vez debería migrarse a [¿Cuáles son los pros y contras a tener en cuenta para elegir entre Angular, ReactJS y Vue?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/304741/cu%c3%a1les-son-los-pros-y-contras-a-tener-en-cuenta-para-elegir-entre-angular-reac#304741)

Comment: Siento que estoy en el cepo y todos me tiran tomates. Al menos voy a quitar mi conclusión sobre la distribución geográfica

Comment: @amenadiel, Tu respuesta lleva un gran trabajo! He creado una [pregunta en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4415/pregunta-basada-en-opiniones-con-respuesta-elaborada?noredirect=1#comment18254_4415) para ver si este sería el sitio para ella. Aun así estaría bastante bien que si puedes/quieres traduzcas esta respuesta a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) como sugiere Ordago en el comentario de la pregunta. Para que tu trabajo no se pierda y ademas pueda servir a mas gente.

Comment: @amenadiel, no te desanimes y sigue colaborando, se ve que tus contribuciones son valiosas. Yo por lo menos he aprendido varias cosas con tu respuesta, así que gracias por tomarte la molestia en escribirla.